# What do these characters say?

Tags: calligraphy

I would be very grateful if anyone could translate the characters on this painting, and maybe tell me the artist name. Thank you[image]

Comment: I’m sorry for violating the rules, I obviously didn’t read the rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably 茶花雙雀 (camellia with two birds) by 阑若. The third written character is probably a variant of 雙, meaning "two". You may help confirm that if there are indeed two birds.

Comment: Hi, yes there are two birds in the picture. You say it is by 阑若, are you able to give a name for these characters, or the chop (I believe) in red? Thanks so much, I love the picture and would love to find out more but have not much idea of how to do so. Thank you for you input!

Comment: Both the characters and the chop (assuming you meant the seal) mean the same thing: i.e., 阑若. The characters in black are more toward the simplified Chinese characters while the chop in red is traditional (with slight variation).

Comment: If you think it answered your question, it will be nice to acknowledge it so that I can get some points (and probably you as well). Thanks!